# ScrollView not scrolling on IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, ios8

I've a problem with the scrollview in IOS 7.
at first, it didn't work at all not even on IOS 7 or IOS 8
but after I added this code:

it starts working on IOS 8 but still not working on IOS 7.

```
[scroll addSubView:contentViewScroll];
scroll.contentSize = contentViewScroll.frame.size;
```

can any one suggest a solution??

Comment: try after disabling autolayout, it may help you

Comment: disabling autolayout not good practice, this will cause a lot other issues

Comment: set the content size in this method -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews { }

Comment: @Ramesh Muthe it didin't works, still not scrolling

Comment: What is the size of `contentViewScroll.frame` when you set it to the scroll's `contentSize`? Is it larger than `scroll.frame` ? If not, there won't be anything to scroll.

Comment: @ Aaron yes its bigger, but its not scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem...

as everybody says, my content size was bigger than the scrollview frame size, but the scroll was not working. after spending hours in this issue, I've managed to fix it by fix all the warning on the controllerview. after all the warnings are fixed the scroll starts to work.

maybe this sounds stupid, but fixing the warnings got the scroll working at last

Answer (score 0):

Your `contentSize` needs to be bigger than your frame size in order for your scroll view to be scrollable.

Comment: its bigger, but its not scrolling